# Why must we take multiple measurements for different values of $M$?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, quantum-phase-estimation

The circuit for Kitaev phase estimation is given as:

[image]

By varying $\theta$, we are able to determine $\sin(2 \pi M \phi_k)$ and $\cos (2 \pi M \phi_k)$ from sampling the circuit and calculating the probabilities of different outputs of the first qubit ($\phi_k$ is a real number, with $e^{2 \pi  i \phi_k}$ being the eigenvalue corresponding to $U$ and $|\xi_k\rangle$). This makes sense, except, the paper I'm reading says we have to take measurements with **different values of $M$** to get maximum precision for our algorithm's output. Why is this the case?

Comment: Can you link the paper?

Comment: @MahathiVempati I'm reading this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.0741.pdf alongside this one https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.00171. Both use the same process for phase estimation.